# Intercept all calls to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I would like to intercept all calls to `$` and `jQuery` functions.  `jQuery()`, `$()`, `$.fn` etc etc otherwise need to work unimpeded.

How can I do this?

Comment: It will probably be faster and easier to just read the javascript and see for yourself where selectors are being abused.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that this is what I am after.

```
(function(){
    var oldJq = window.jQuery;

    window.jQuery = function(){
        window.jQuery.anthony.calls++;
        return oldJq.apply(null, arguments);
    };

    window.jQuery.anthony = {
        calls: 0
    };

    for (var prop in oldJq)
        if (oldJq.hasOwnProperty(prop))
            window.jQuery[prop] = oldJq[prop];

    window.jQuery.prototype = oldJq.prototype;
    window.$ = window.jQuery;
})();
```

Note that this will not intercept any functions called on jquery objects.

Comment: I see you're attempting to answer your own question, but I don't see how this "counts where selectors are getting abused" which is what your question asked.  This provides a hook for the top-level jQuery constructor, but doesn't do anything about seeing what is being abused and doesn't monitor any jQuery methods that also use selectors.

Comment: Ah yes I updated the question.  The vast majority in my case are using `$('....')`, but there will be others that use the traversal functions.  This one was just about the top-level function.